# Laravel 7 / SQL case insensitive where clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Have a problem on getting data from the DB.
The problem is, that the search query uses case sensitive parameters, which I don't want.

Need a solution, to find all database fields without case sensitivity and exactly as the string is, no text after, and before.

Example:

First I get the data: `$affiliateOpens = AffiliateOpen::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();`

Then, I convert the strings I will be searching throught to lowercase, like so (Because there are many records with different charachter cases:

```
$sources = [];
    foreach ($affiliateOpensCollection  as $affiliateOpen)
        $sources[] = strtolower($affiliateOpen->source);

 foreach ($uniqueSources as $source) {
        $sourceData[$source]['installs'] = count($affiliatesOpenCollection->where('source', $source)->where('date_installed', '<>', null));
 }
```

How could I search without case sensitivity and get the data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
   $sourceData[$source]['installs'] = count($affiliatesOpenCollection->filter(function ($item) use ($source) {
            return (strtolower($item['source']) == strtolower($source) && $item['date_installed'] != null);
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereRaw does not exist.